# From Input field is not auto-resizing in React/Javascript/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am facing difficulty when resizing the `input field` in the `form`, i have tried to tweak few other things including representing the width in `%` but still no success, i think i am missing something here but not sure.

Any help appreciated.

-Snippet of code

```
 <div style={{ width: "32rem", paddingTop: "5rem", marginLeft: "0px", justifyContent: "left" }}>
      {
        // <form method="POST" className="formstyle" onSubmit={credentialVerify}>

        <form method="POST" onSubmit={credentialVerify}>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "0.75rem", padding: "0.75rem" }} className="form-group">
            <label for="enterEmail">Email address</label>

            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              placeholder="email"
              id="enterEmail"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={updateEmail}
              style={{ width: "40rem" }}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ paddingLeft: "0.75rem" }} className="form-group ">
            <label for="enterPassword " class="form-check-label">
              Password
            </label>

            <input
              style={{ width: "40rem" }}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Password"
              class="form-control"
              name="password"
              id="enterPassword"
              value={password}
              onChange={updatePassword}
            />
            <ButtonGroup style={{ paddingTop: "3rem" }}>
              <Button className=" buttonBlock" variant="primary" type="submit" style={{ height: "3rem", width: "40rem", marginLeft: "0px", justifyContent: "left" }}>
                Submit
              </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </div>
        </form>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

- `Screenshot` of window in full screen

[image]

- `Screenshot` of window when resizing and only the `input` & `button` field doenst resize

[image]

Comment: Hi do you want to center align it on all devices..Are you comfortable using flexbox may I can help you with flexbox

Comment: yes please, any help appreciated.

Comment: Sure..Give me some time I will send sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-platform-4exg1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have a look at this Idea is maincontainer has to be flex column with align items at center and then child component would be center aligned

Comment: Did this help??

Comment: Hi  sgrmhdk , Thanks for this. let me have a look.

Comment: Thanks sgrmhdk , i tried but its not working as i intended. i am using form-group here, so i am not sure if it is something to do with it.